# IIS: Blank Sites created with Name SITE_XX

Tags: powershell, iis-7, wix

We've got an automated deploy script which deletes the current websites using the `WebAdministration` powershell provider, then runs an installer (created using Wix - version 3) to install a new version of the website.

The issue is that after the installer runs a whole slew of blank websites are being created all with names like `SITE_102`, `SITE_103` (where the numeric part matches the site ID). IIS is using an incremental algorithm to generate the IDs (as described here: http://blogs.iis.net/carlosag/archive/2008/06/13/iis-7-0-site-id-computation.aspx). It looks as if the "Next ID" is not only not being reset (fair enough), but when the installer creates the site, blank sites are being created to fill the gap from one upwards.

My question is, is this IIS - or a bug in the Wix IIS implementation? What can be done to prevent this? Currently we're working around it by deleting all the junk sites, but the numbers seem to be getting larger - and this step is starting to take a while.

Edit: I Should also note, that this only started happening when we starting using the powershell script to uninstall and delete the sites.

Comment: Have you followed steps similar to [these](http://blog.lukesmith.net/2010/01/17/creating-website-installer-using-wix/) to create the site with WIX?

Comment: Yep, the site creates just fine, it's just the whole stack of extra sites that are annoying.

Comment: Have you recycled IIS after running your powershell before running your installer to confirm the sites have really gone?